# Getting data(contacts, images, downloads, browser's history etc) from content providers or cursorLoaders

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app which will have multiple buttons (show images, show downloads, show contacts, browser's history etc). Basically, on clicking each button the user will be displayed all the data using a CursorLoader and content provider of that URI.

however, I've been going through developers.Android code snippets but am unable to understand the complete code properly for I want understand the code completely for at least one application ( eg contacts list ) so that I can make others easily.

I'm a beginner in Android, please help me on the same.